# mysql query for password should not be last three passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have pwd_history table containing columns id(PK),old_password, created_date,user_id. When ever user modify the password an extra row will be added to that table.I want a single query through which it should verify the entered password is in last three passwords modified by the user. Is there a way in Mysql? thanks.

Comment: Are you storing those old passwords *in plaintext*?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how your database looks? `oldpasswords` could be anything from a typo of `oldpassword` to a comma seperated field with multiple hashes.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: what's wrong with the question??

Comment: @AravindKishore You want the last 3 passwords, but are these on three rows, are they comma seperated in `oldpasswords`, are they seperated by another thing? We have no clue, as you haven't told us.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: why you are so specific about how password is hashed.The main concept in the question is to comparing with oldpasswords. Mostly every one knows how to compare entered passwords with old passwords using their respective hashing.

Comment: @AravindKishore What are you on about? What you're asking is "how to match with the last 3 passwords". Where are these last 3 passwords? In 3 rows inside `pwd_history`? In one row as comma seperated values in `pwd_history`? In a completely different table? If you haven't saved the old password hashes anywhere, why do you expect to be able to "verify" them against a value you haven't saved? If you have saved it, where have you saved it? You never describe this. According to your accepted answer it's 3 rows, but the column is called `old_passwords` with an s, indicating multiple passwords.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yes, I can accept that people will get confused because of an extra 's' in the filed name but you would have got that with created_date field or at least you would have asked that what the purpose of keeping created_date.And one more thing that who will verify anything against unsaved value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the password was hashed with mysql's default `password`, then
try this, with valid input values:

***Updated***:

```
select * from (
   select * from old_pwds_table
     where user_id=input_id
     order by created_date desc
     limit 3
) a 
where 
 old_password=password('new password')
```

---

***Former answer***:

```
select * from old_pwds_table
  where user_id=input_id
    and old_password=password('new password')
  order by created_date desc
  limit 3
```

Comment: it won't work as it checks all entries where old_pwd = new_pwd but I want to check only last three passwords modified by the user. If new_pwd is last fourth one it should accept.

Comment: can I know what this sub query type is called??

Comment: It is an *inline* `View`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this function hope It helps to you:

```
function check_old_pass($new_pwd){
    $result=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from old_pwds_table
        where user_id=input_id
        and old_password=$new_pwd
        order by created_date desc
        limit 0,3"));
    if ($result==1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    pwd_history
WHERE
    user_id = 'USER_ID' 
AND 
    oldpasswords = 'NEW_PASSWORD' 
ORDER BY 
    created_date DESC 
LIMIT 3
```